# Empty C# program results in unexpectedly large output file size

Tags: c#, .net

I am experiencing an issue where even a minimal C# program with no logic or dependencies results in a surprisingly large output file size. I expect an empty program to produce a small executable, but the file size is around 140 MB.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Empty program
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is because of the Self-Contained.

Comment: "with no logic or dependencies" - you mean apart from the dependency of "the full runtime and libraries" because you've put it in self-contained mode?

Comment: You elected to include the entire .NET 6 runtime *and* compile the application with Read-to-Run. This compiles at least some assemblies to native code which takes more space than IL. I suspect trimming wasn't enabled either. In any case trimming wasn't as effective in .NET 6 as it is in .NET 8. If you want to test how large a natively compiled application is, try with .NET 8

Comment: I tried downloading .net 7 in 50 MB and my compiled program with .net was 1 MB so it is around of 50 MB then why self-contained is 140?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your Deployment mode from Self-contained to framework-dependent in order not to include all .NET Core binaries that are making your project that large.

See [Deploy .NET Core apps with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156#simpleSelf).

Comment: I don't want it to be depended on .net I want it to be self contained. But my question is why an empty project must be 140 MB? (I tried a 12000 lines of code program and it was still 140 MB)

Comment: @tomatobar An empty project is 140 MB because that's how big the runtime is. For it to be able to run *literally any code* (even an empty function), it *needs* the runtime. Because you told it to be self-contained, the runtime gets packaged with it the program can still run without the system having the runtime installed. Also 12000 lines of code is a few hundred thousand short of 1 MB, which is why the file size stayed the same (because it is the same).